# emit() and on() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm learning nodejs and some issues appeared, that emit() and on() is not a function..

here's my emitter.js fie

```js
   function Emitter(){
    this.events = {};
}

Emitter.prototype.on = function(type, listener){
    this.events[type]=this.events[type]||[];
    this.events[type].push(listener);
}

Emitter.prototype.emit = function(type){
    if (this.events[type]) {
        this.events[type].forEach(function(listener){
            listener();
        });
    }
}
```

and here's my app.js file

```js
//Emitter
var Emitter = require('./emitter');
Emitter.on('greet', function(){
    console.log('a greeting occured!`');
});
console.log('hello');
Emitter.emit('greet');
```

and here's the error
`TypeError: Emitter.on is not a function`

when i instantiated the Emitter:
`var emitter = new Emitter();`

and this the error:
`TypeError: Emitter is not a constructor`
then, i export the modules using this literal syntax:
`module.exports= {emit: Emit}`
the error still appeared that `the new Emitter() is not a constructor`

so, i export it with this:
`module.exports = Emitter;` instead with this pattern `module.exports = {emit: Emitter}` and i still don't know why i can't export it with literal, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a class. Create an instance of it using `new Emitter()`. Also, you have to export and import the `Emitter` class:

```js
// emitter.js
function Emitter(){
  this.events = {};
}

Emitter.prototype.on = function(type, listener){
  this.events[type]=this.events[type]||[];
  this.events[type].push(listener);
}

Emitter.prototype.emit = function(type){
  if (this.events[type]) {
    this.events[type].forEach(function(listener){
      listener();
    });
  }
}
// Export the Emitter class: module.exports = Emitter;

// app.js
// Import the emitter class: var Emitter = require('./emitter');
var emitter = new Emitter();
emitter.on('greet', function(){
  console.log('a greeting occured!`');
});
console.log('hello');
emitter.emit('greet');
```

Whenever you use the `new` operator with a constructor function, a new object is created. The prototype of that object will the `prototype` property of the constructor function. Then, the constructor is called with the new object (`this` in the constructor is the new object).

Comment: i've did it, and other issues appeared TypeError: Emitter is not a constructor

Comment: Because you didn't export the class. Look at the comment in my snippet.

Comment: can i use the object literal syntax to export the module like this `module.exports = {emit: Emitter}`
if i can, the error still appeared that new Emitter() is not a constructor.. any idea?

Comment: i did wht u said using `module.exports = Emitter;` instead `module.exports = { emit: Emitter}` and its working but i don't know why i cant export it with object literal?

Comment: If you export an object, then you will get the same object when requiring the module. If you really want to do that, then you have to do: `var Emitter = require('...').emit;`.

Comment: wait, what that last `.emit` used for, can u explain a bit? thanks in advance

Comment: Well, in `{emit: Emitter}`, the `emit` property contains the class that you want to access. Using require, you will get a reference to the exported object. If you want to get access to the class, you have to use the `emit` property of that object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that should be addressed, firstly you need to export the `Emitter` function from the file that it was defined in to be able to `require` it in another file, you can do this simply like this:

```
module.exports = function Emitter() {
  this.events = {}
}

// ... etc
```

You also need to use the `new` operator on your `Emitter` function to instantiate a new copy of the object to allow you to then use the functions `on` and `emit` that you defined. This is because the methods are part of the [objects prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype). You can do this like this:

```
const emitter = new Emitter()

emitter.on("greet", function () {
  // ... etc
})
```

> It might be worth noting that Node.js already has an inbuilt Events module that covers what you are trying to achieve, and you can find documentation in their [API docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).

Comment: i've did it, and other issues appeared `TypeError: Emitter is not a constructor`

Comment: You need to export the emitter from the file that it was defined in, otherwise you won't be able to use it, have you done that?

Comment: not yet, so must export the emitter with this  `module.exports = { emitter: Emitter}` ?

Comment: Just module.exports = Emitter